# sqlite3 TypeError: 'url' is an invalid keyword

Tags: sqlite, url, typeerror

When I execute python3 script which contain

```
    conn_1 = sqlite3.connect('file:content.sqlite?mode=ro', uri=True)#read only
```

I have an error

```
    conn_1 = sqlite3.connect('file:content.sqlite?mode=ro', url=True)#read only
TypeError: 'url' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

How to solve that problem?

Comment: You've got `url=True` (you are ell) it should be `uri=True` (you are eye).

Comment: I've used with 'uri' also - the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue, `uri` param was introduced by sqlite3 python module from version 3.4 onwards as per the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#connection-objects). You can upgrade your python version to 3.9.x as sqlite3 comes as a part of python standard library.

Comment: Its seems they asked about `url` not `uri`?

Comment: `uri` is the correct parameter for sqlite connection as per the docs.